# Script in Oracle unsuccessful in execution - Jmeter

Tags: oracle, automation, jmeter

I have the following situation:

I want to run scripts in Oracle, using JDBC Request in Jmeter.
The connection configuration is now ok.

When I run the script, I get an error. And a detail: The same script within PL/SQL is successfully executed.
Error: "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character".

Does anyone know why?

Script:

```
SELECT *FROM TBJDALRT_ALERTA_TP;
```

Prints below (script and error).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqAia.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k83Br.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Remove `;` character

Comment: Hmm.. and why can't I run two selects? In SQL I can. Not in Oracle.

Comment: Example: SELECT *FROM TBJDALRT_ALERTA_TP
SELECT *FROM TBJDCTCCIP_ARQV_REC_LG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `;` from your statement. Executing several SQL statements in one JDBC Request sampler is not supported, you either need to switch to [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) language and invoke [Statement.executeBatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) function or go for 2 separate JDBC Request samplers.

More information: [Apache Groovy - Working with a relational database](https://groovy-lang.org/databases.html)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri T.